# Regex get array number

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, string, input

I'm trying to isolate array name and array size from code. This example of expected input:

```
blah_blah[blahvar]
blah_ha[2]
blah_[]
```

I need to match names (blah_blah, blah_ha, blah_) and text inside brackets (blahvar, 2, '').
I have this regex:

```
([a-zA-z_]+)(\[[a-zA-Z_]*\])
```

But it's not working. Please help.

Comment: "It's not working" is *never* a good enough description of the problem. What's wrong? Does it match too much? Too little? Does it match the right things but you're having trouble extracting the groups?

Comment: This is probably not the cause of your problem, but first part of the regex ([a-zA-z_]+) has lowercase 'z' instead of uppercase 'Z'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include numbers:

`([a-zA-z_0-9]+)(\[[a-zA-Z_0-9]*\])`

Without that, your second example `blah_ha[2]` won't catch (the others do).

A shorter version (that captures every word character (letters, digits,  etc.):

`(\w+)(\[\w*\])`

Answer (score 3):

Use This regular expression

```
([\w]+)\[([\w]*)\]
```

Group 1 will match the array name and Group 2 will match the index